# jquery on scroll not working in firefox, but working in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

page: http://kafe.aweb.kz
sticky menu works in chrome but not in firefox 26, IE 11

CSS:

```
.header-scrollable-wrapper {
    background: url("images/header_bg.png") repeat 0 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.header-scrollable-wrapper.clone {
    position: fixed;
    top: -50px;
    transition: 0.2s top ease-in;
}

body.down .header-scrollable-wrapper.clone {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

JS:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $header = $(".header-scrollable-wrapper"),
            $clone = $header.before($header.clone().addClass("clone"));

        $(window).on("scroll", function() {
            var fromTop = $("body").scrollTop();
            $('body').toggleClass("down", (fromTop > 245));
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

What might be causing it?

Comment: check that fromTop  is the expected value. I guess FF and IE return always 0. Test using instead `$(document).scrollTop();`

Comment: It's always zero in firefox, but in chrome it shows the value.

Comment: Oh! it works with $(document).scrollTop(); i guess firefox and ie won't work with $('body').scrollTop(); why?